# Reconnect everytime to mysql with Grape

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, api, ruby-grape

I am a ruby beginner and I have a question about how to use mysql with grape.

Do I have to call `Mysql.new()` everytime I want to use my database or is there a better way to do this?

I tried to make the new in `initialize` of my `class API < Grape::API` but it doesn't seem to work...

Any suggestion?

EDIT: Here is some code of something i did and that works fine, but i would like to improve this by not connecting to sql everytime if possible:

```
class API < Grape::API

  before do
   header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
   @db_co = Mysql.new("localhost", "root", "toto", "youfight_userapp")
  end

 resource :users do

  get :toto do
   result = @db_co.query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 104")
   result.fetch_row
  end

 end
end
```

Comment: If you add instance variables to your API class, they aren't always accessible in the way you expect in Grape. For instance, all your routes become separate `Grape::Endpoint` objects. I suggest you paste up some code in the question, just a minimal version of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to use some kind of ORM. We ran into a lot of issues when we were trying to write ours API the way you are yours and in the end we switched to ORM. We choose [datamapper](http://datamapper.org/), but there are lots of other choices. For example [sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) seems to be quite solid.